# webClient.DownloadDataCompleted event

Tags: c#, multithreading

Small and easy question (strangely I couldn't find the answer here or by Google).
when the event is raised of webClient.DownloadDataCompleted is it raised on th ui thread or on the DownloadDataAsyn thread? meanning do I need to use beginInvoke (winform) to update the ui or directly access the Ui control.

Of course I can test it but this is foundamental question: the events handlers are normally raise on the executed thread right? so I suspect beginInvoke is indeed needed here so If not what is the reason?

Comment: It depends on where you invoked `DownloadDataAsync`. If you invoked it from the UI thread, you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebClient is aware of synchronization context of current thread.

If you call DownloadDataAsync on UI thread, DownloadDataCompleted will be posted to that UI thread.

Threads other than UI thread will normally have no synchronization context, starting DownloadDataAsync on such thread will cause DownloadDataCompleted to run on any available thread.

"C# 5.0 in an Nutshell" book describes synchronization context in rich clients.